# Java HashMap.remove(key) VS HashMap.put(key,null) - Which is faster?

Tags: java

I wonder if `HashMap.put(key,null)` has better performance over `HashMap.remove(key)` or not ?

Comment: Possible repeat? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091148/hashmaps-and-null-values

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Finally please read this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Comment: "which is better?" do yo mean which is **faster**?

Comment: The two approaches are not equivalent. The call to `remove(key)` will actually remove the mapping whereas the call to `put(key, null)` will simply map the key to `null`. In other words, even after calling the latter, a call to `containsKey(key)` will return `true`. If your goal is to remove an entry from the map then use `remove`. And note that `Map` implementations are not required to allow `null` values and could instead throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which approach you use in your code. HashMap.put(key,null)  is different  from HashMap.remove(key) as put is used for adding some value and remove is used for removing. The time complexity of HasMap is O(1). As both are used in HashMap so their time Complexity will be same.So i think they both are faster.

Comment: Both the operations refers to Hashmap and the time complexity for Hashmap is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Which one is better totally depends on how you use your `HashMap` in your code since they are two different methods doing two different things.

If you are *only* considering performance and if you are *merely* curious about which one is faster, there would be no big difference since `HashMap` has time complexity of **O(1)** for both `put` and `remove`.

I am guessing there might be a small performance benefit for `remove` since it reduces the total number of keys in `HashMap` and it is definitely possible for `HashMap` to have time complexity of O(n) in the worst case, but I think it is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

On top of @Slaw's comment, if you use `HashMap.put(key,null)` in lieu of `HashMap.remove(key)`, the size of the map would not change. This could cause unintended side effects.

```
    Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println("Size: " + test.size());  // Size: 0

    test.put("John", null);
    System.out.println("Size: " + test.size());  // Size: 1
```